# How to type \\ as a code block in comments using mini markdown

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, markdown

How do I type double backlash, also known as the escape key, in a code block using mini Markdown?

When typing in a question or an answer the syntax is the same, ` + \\ + ` will correctly form `\\`, but using the mini Markdown for the comments, it does not work do that. But according to the *help*, it's supposed to work the same.

So how are you supposed to type `\\` correctly in a comment?

Comment: `\\ ` Add a space at the end.